# Showing this set is open in the topological space $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, box-topology

Let $\pi_1 : \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be the projection on the first coordinate. Let $A$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ consisting of all points $(x,y)$ for which either $x\geqslant 0$ or $y=0$ (or both) and let $q:A\to \mathbb{R}$ be obtained by restricting $\pi_1$

To prove that the function $q$ is continuous I have to show that for an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that the set below is open in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

$\left((U \cap [0,\infty)\right)\times \mathbb{R}) \cup (U\times \{0\})$

The function is continuous and so the set should be open. However, $[0,\infty)$ and $\{0\}$ are not open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and so I don't see how this set is in the box topology of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not. Maybe it's an alternate characterization of continuous functions? It might be worthwhile to mention the function you're dealing with as well, and why you choose that particular set.

Comment: I edited the post to include the function if that helps

Comment: You want to show that the preimage of $U$ is open in $A$, not $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, which is different.

Comment: ok. so $q^{-1}(U)=(\mathbb{U} \times \mathbb{R}) \cap A$ which is open in the subspace box topology?

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and if $A$ is a subspace of $X$ then $f|_ A,$ the restriction of $f$ to $A,$ is continuous from the space $A$ to $Y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q^{-1}(U)=(U \times \mathbb{R}) \cap A$. Since $U \times \mathbb{R}$ is a product of open sets, it is open in $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ and so the intersection with $A$ is open in the subspace $A$ by definition of the subspace topology.

Comment: $U\times\Bbb R$ is open, as the product of open sets.  And it follows that the intersection with $A$ is open in $A$.